# Small size or small sized?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

We always refer to our clients' companies as *small, medium or large*. My question is which one of these is correct?

> We provide web and mobile solutions to small size companies.

> We provide web and mobile solutions to small sized companies.

Comment: @ MaulikV This is something I've often wondered, and I think there is a general difference in preference between AmE and BrE. As per the comments to the answer, small/medium/large do not require -size/-sized, but perhaps you are thinking of something like *bite-size* vs *bite-sized*?

Comment: For the record: a small company, a medium-size or medium-sized company and a large company.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot speak to English elsewhere, but in the US there would be no need to use *size* at all—‘small business’ is the term.

If you are concerned that bare *small* suggests inferiority, quite the opposite is true. ‘Small businesses’ are generally recognized—or at least recognize themselves!—as the engine which drives the American economy, and there is a large Federal agency, the Small Business Administration, dedicated to their support. They have indeed something of a mystique: ‘small business owners’ regard themselves as a distinct class, superior in efficiency, energy and entrepreneurship to the bureaucratic managers of large corporations.

Of course the US notion of ‘small business’ may be substantially larger than that which obtains in your country. The SBA standard varies from industry to industry, but by and large it is less than 500 employees in manufacturing and less than $7M annual revenue in non-manufacturing industries.

Comment: My concern is learning the usage of the word 'size' or 'sized' than understanding the 'scale' of businesses. It is more about mentioning the size of the company rather than justifying it with its revenue and the like. Anyway, for your reference, here is an article on The Washington Post that reads 'mid-size': http://www.washingtonpost.com/business/capitalbusiness/big-law-firms-are-losing-fees-to-mid-size-firms/2013/10/29/4c2ec2ec-3ceb-11e3-a94f-b58017bfee6c_story.html

Comment: There is a book on managing a midsized (here, it's 'sized') company: http://www.amazon.com/Managing-The-Small-Midsized-Company/dp/0256142807 by an American business consultant, author, and lecturer on the subject of company sustainability and growth.

Comment: @MaulikV You asked about *small*, and my point was that  *size* is not used with *small* ... the spectrum is *small, mid-size(d), large*. *Mid* needs *size* because it's basically an adverb, not an adjective. You can use *medium* internally, but that's mostly used of packaging.

Comment: O.k. Got it. In India it's too frequently used even for small and large businesses. Thank you.

Comment: @MaulikV I cannot say too strongly that you should be guided by the language of **your audience**, not mine. For instance, a 'small business' in Australia may imply fewer than 15 employees, in the EU fewer than 50. It may be that in India the phrase *small business* would suggest unimportance. If that is the case, then its use in the US is irrelevant, and *small-size* (or *small size* or *small sized*) would be more appropriate for you, to make it clear that you are speaking only of scale. What is the usage in India? --follow that.

Comment: I will echo StoneyB's recommendation, however there might be an exception where it is advisable to opt for the standard English phrase most widely accepted. On a company's website, if you are trading with businesses in Europe, N.America and in Asia (and elsewhere) then it is sensible to employ grammatically correct expressions, collocations and idioms which will promote a positive image of the company.

Comment: @Mari-LouA That's a good point. If you're addressing diverse audiences you should consider using different discourses--for instance, separate sites for Indian and World readers.

Comment: @StoneyB *mid* an adverb? http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/mid?q=mid

Comment: @MaulikV I don't much care for that parse. My own take on it is that *mid* isn't a 'word' but a combining form, and it's only the recent orthographic tendency to detach it that makes it look like a word.

Answer (score 0):

I think we should consider this problem from a grammar view, rather than taking this problem into a specific situation. We talk about it because we want to learn how to format a new word correctly.

"small size companies" is noun + noun where the first noun is "small size" and the second noun is "companies".
"small sized companies" is adj + noun where the adjective is "small sized" and the noun is "companies".

In [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/small-sized), it says "small-sized" and "small-size" are both OK.

> **small-sized**: small, or available in a small size:
> *a small-sized company/business/industry*.
> **small-size**: →  small-sized *However, the feeding activity of these taxa does not necessarily avoid small-size prey such as protozoa.*

Comment: If you do not have enough knowledge it is better not to post an answer.

Comment: The first answer leads to a practical view and I use my answer to lead this problem back to a grammar view. I try my best to contribute to this problem, but the only thing you know is to deny others.

Comment: Sorry that it came across that way. Please have a look at the [tour](https://ell.stackexchange.com/tour). Your point may be good, but it does not make an answer, which is why it was downvoted (not by me). I am just trying to prepare you for future objections that's all. Good luck.

Comment: I got you, and I have read the tour. It's really helpful that there's someone who can tell me how to present a better answer in this website. I love this website even more.