# How can I improve this sentence about the German "Kleinunternehmer"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, phrase-usage, translation

I'm looking for the correct translation of the German word "**Kleinunternehmer**". The translations I found are *individual businesses*, *small entrepreneurs*, *small businesses*, etc., but I'm not sure which of them to use.

The text I'm trying to translate is a note for an order form which gives the users the information that the business owner is, based on a certain legal regulation, exempted from the value added tax (VAT).

> "Gemäß § 19 UStG sind wir als Kleinunternehmer von der MwSt.
>       freigestellt."

Unfortunately I wasn't able to come up with something which seemed correct to me. This is what I've got so far:

> "As entrepreneurs we are according to § 19 UStG exempt from VAT."

Is there a chance to improve this?

Comment: In the US, the legal term is 'small business owners'; see [this question](http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/13363/32), particularly the comments to the Answer. An entirely different term may be appropriate in other jurisdictions.

Comment: One way to translate the nature of the business to which "Kleinunternehmer" refers would be, almost literally, "a small undertaking", but "a small undertaker" has a very different meaning! One could also say "a small enterprise", but I can't think of anything for the person other than what StoneyB suggests or, depending on the particulars, "contractors".

Comment: @StoneyB Thanks for the answer, would it be then grammatically correct if I would phrase it like this: "As small business owners we are according to § 19 UStG exempt from VAT."?

Comment: @Teo Exactly, though you may shove the phrases around any way you like. I'd write it "As small business owners we are exempt from VAT under § 19 UStG."

Comment: @StoneyB Thanks a lot, I will write it the way you would! +1

Comment: @Teo [Linguee.com](http://www.linguee.com/english-german?query=kleinunternehmer&source=german) is a useful source. And iIf you have to do much of this you may want to look at the [DGT-Translation Memory](http://ipsc.jrc.ec.europa.eu/index.php?id=197), a corpus of official translations from the European Commission’s Directorate-General for Translation.

Comment: @StoneyB Thanks a lot for that link, I've got a few more translations to take care of and it will be helpful for me...

Comment: @Teo You're welcome. Be warned that Linguee sometimes highlights the wrong words as the translation of your search term; but you know enough English to spot those errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[StoneyB](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/32/stoneyb) recommends translating *“Kleinunternehmer”* as “small business owners”.

> **Small Business**
> Small businesses are normally privately owned corporations, partnerships, or sole proprietorships. What constitutes "small" in terms of government support and tax policy varies depending on the country and industry.
> <sub>Source: [Wikipedia entry – Small business](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small_business_owner)</sub>

There is some flexibility to how you order things in this sentence, but the most natural way is probably:

> As small business owners, we are exempt from VAT under § 19 UStG.

If you wanted to stay closer to the order in the original statement, you could write:

> According to § 19 UStG, we small businesses are exempt from VAT.

Answer (score 0):

According to this website https://leitsch.org/blog/ein-kleinunternehmen-gruenden-und-alles-was-dazu-gehoert "Kleinunternehmen" in the legal sense in Germany is a single person trading with an annual revenue of at most €17,500. I would suggest that for a UK audience, "sole trader" is most likely a much better translation. A "small business" is very unlikely to be VAT exempt (according to German rules), a "sole trader" quite possibly is.